# How to overcome a ERROR: Aborted in NodeJS calling a stored procedure - pendingoperations.js using NODEJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I've been very successful in making NodeJS API calls to SQL Server stored procedures nicely.

I get the first one:

```
let query;
query = env.STOREDPROCS.GET.PHONETYPES; // to add input var put @varname='' <-- VALUE
let db = {};
module.exports = db;

initializeDB();

async function initializeDB() {
  sql
    .connect(config)
    .then((dbConn) => {
      console.log("connected for phonetypes: ", query);

      dbConn.query(query, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error getting PhoneTypes from Stored Proc: ", err);
          sql.close();
        }
        if (data) {
          console.log("ALL PHONE TYPES RETRIEVED: ", data);
          phonetypesDataArray.push(data.recordset);
          console.log("RECORDSET PHONETYPES: ", phonetypesDataArray);
          db.PhoneTypesModel = phonetypesDataArray;
          console.log("Phone Types Model: ", db.PhoneTypesModel);
          sql.close();
          return db.PhoneTypesModel;
        } else {
          let errmsg =
            "NO RECORDS RETURNED for " + env.STOREDPROCS.GET.PHONETYPES;
          console.log(errmsg);
          phonetypesDataArray.push({ error: errmsg });
          sql.close();
          return phonetypesDataArray;
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error", err);
      errmsg = `"Error Connecting to Database: ", ${err}`;
      phonetypesDataArray.push(errmsg);
      return phonetypesDataArray;
    });
}
```

But, when I do the exact same thing with another stored procedure for getting Military Service Branches, like so,

```
let db = {};
module.exports = db;

initializeDB();

async function initializeDB() {
  sql
    .connect(config)
    .then((dbConn) => {
      console.log("connected inside GET BRANCHES");

      dbConn.query(query, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error getting BRANCHES OF SERVICE from Stored Proc: ", err);
          sql.close();
        }
        if (data) {
          console.log("ALL BRANCHES OF SERVICE RETRIEVED: ", data);
          branchOfSvcDataArray.push(data.recordset);
          console.log("RECORDSET BRANCHES OF SERVICE: ", branchOfSvcDataArray);
          db.branchOfSvcDataArray = phonetypesDataArray;
          console.log("Branches of Service Model: ", db.branchOfSvcDataArray);
          sql.close();
          return db.branchOfSvcDataArray;
        } else {
          let errmsg =
            "NO RECORDS RETURNED for " + env.STOREDPROCS.GET.BRANCHESOFSVC;
          console.log(errmsg);
          branchOfSvcDataArray.push({ error: errmsg });
          sql.close();
          return branchOfSvcDataArray;
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error", err);
      errmsg = `"Error Connecting to Database: ", ${err}`;
      branchOfSvcDataArray.push(errmsg);
      return branchOfSvcDataArray;
    });
}
```

I get this error:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening on port number: 8000
connected for phonetypes:  usp_getPhoneTypes
connected branches of service
connected column info
connected db-conn
connected for getting column info:  usp_getColumnInforForADB
connected inside GET BRANCHES
ALL PHONE TYPES RETRIEVED:  {
  recordsets: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [
    { phone_types_id: 1, phone_type_name: 'CELL', rowCnt: 3 },
    { phone_types_id: 2, phone_type_name: 'HOME', rowCnt: 3 },
    { phone_types_id: 3, phone_type_name: 'WORK', rowCnt: 3 }
  ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: []
}
RECORDSET PHONETYPES:  [
  [
    { phone_types_id: 1, phone_type_name: 'CELL', rowCnt: 3 },
    { phone_types_id: 2, phone_type_name: 'HOME', rowCnt: 3 },
    { phone_types_id: 3, phone_type_name: 'WORK', rowCnt: 3 }
  ]
]
Phone Types Model:  [
  [
    { phone_types_id: 1, phone_type_name: 'CELL', rowCnt: 3 },
    { phone_types_id: 2, phone_type_name: 'HOME', rowCnt: 3 },
    { phone_types_id: 3, phone_type_name: 'WORK', rowCnt: 3 }
  ]
]
```

> Error getting BRANCHES OF SERVICE from stored procedure.
> Error: aborted
>
> at PendingOperation.abort (C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:25:21)
> at C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:208:25
> at Array.map ()
> at C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:207:53
> at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
> at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
>
> NO RECORDS RETURNED for usp_getBranches
>
> C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:25
> this.reject(new Error('aborted'));
>
> Error: aborted
> at PendingOperation.abort (C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\PendingOperation.js:25:21)
> at C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:208:25
> at Array.map ()
> at C:\node-rest-api\node_modules\tarn\dist\Pool.js:207:53
> at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
> at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
>
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Thank you Marc.... I do have a tendency to get "wordy"

Comment: It looks like you're running two queries in paralell, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: where is `usp_getBranches` in your script? (is that part missing?) do you pass parameters  to it?  are these the right types, in the right order, and the correct number of them? are you using the mssql package?

Comment: The `async` keywords decorating functions suggest to me that the caller is `await`ing these functions. Have you tried committing to one pattern, [async/await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait) or [promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises)?